# Missing return type in array.map

Tags: typescript, eslint

I got Eslint warning in following TypeScript code:

"Missing return type on function.eslint(@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)" The warning refers the lambda in map function.

```
private headerSelectionChanged(event): void {
    const { checked } = event.syntheticEvent.target;
    const newGridData = this.props.gridData.map(item => Object.assign(item, { selected: checked }));
    this.updateGridData(newGridData);
}
```

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning shows because your mapping function does not specify a return type. You have to specify the return type like this:

```
const newGridData = this.props.gridData.map((item): any => Object.assign(item, { selected: checked }));
```

Keep in mind that [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) modifies the target instead of copying it. If you do not want `this.props.gridData` to be modified, you should swap `item` and `{ selected: checked }`

```
const newGridData = this.props.gridData.map((item): any => Object.assign({ selected: checked }, item));
```

or use the newer [object spread operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html), if available:

```
const newGridData = this.props.gridData.map((item): any => ({ ...item, selected: checked }));
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding types like :

```
private headerSelectionChanged(event: any): void {
const { checked } = event.syntheticEvent.target;
const newGridData = this.props.gridData.map((item: any) => Object.assign(item, { selected: checked }));
this.updateGridData(newGridData);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make out what type "newGridData" is supposed to be. But let's say it is supposed to be an array of some type named "GridData".

```
private headerSelectionChanged(event): void {
    const { checked } = event.syntheticEvent.target;
    const newGridData = this.props.gridData.map<GridData>(item => Object.assign(item, { selected: checked }));
    this.updateGridData(newGridData);
}
```